# Allowing full html to be parsed in HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

This is a problem I've had for a long time - I currently accept a full html page from the user as input and want to filter / clean it out. the problem with HTMLpurifier is that it removes the head , html , and body tags - as well as the styles in the head. I've google , looked at the forums , tried implementing what was written , and to no luck. Can someone help ?

What I want : To keep the HTML , HEAD , STYLE , BODY TAGS

What I have done :

```
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'test');
    $config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
    $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array('html','head', 'body', 'style', 'div', 'p'));    

    if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
        $def->addElement('html', 'Block', 'Inline', 'Common', array());
        $def->addElement('head', 'Block', 'Inline', 'Common', array());
        $def->addElement('style', 'Block', 'Inline', 'Common', array());
        $def->addElement('body', 'Block', 'Inline', 'Common', array());

    }
```

Comment: You basically need to change the whitelist to allow more stuff. Have you read http://htmlpurifier.org/docs#toclink1?

Comment: The purifier strips out several things but you don't say what you want to strip with it and what you expect the outcome to be. Please clarify your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Added , above are the current approach I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End Result - HTMLPurfier does not natively allow full HTML Parsing - Either extend it or find a pass thru

Comment: Until now. It's perfectly possible to implement this in userland.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use strip_tags? It supports list of allowed tags.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: PHP's strip_tags is not a safe way to protect against XSS attacks. It also strips many other things than HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
$config->set('Core.ConvertDocumentToFragment', false);
```

For whatever reason, `Core.ConvertDocumentToFragment` defaults to `true`, even though the documentation states that ["for most inputs, this processing is not necessary"](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.ConvertDocumentToFragment).

I was bitten by this too. All I got from the error collector was the cryptic message "Removed document metadata tags", which in turn is a translation from the internal message "Lexer: Extracted body".

Answer (score 0):

It requires some amount of work, but it is possible to implement this yourself.

All steps would be too much to explain here, but I've encountered the exact same problem. I wanted to sanitize HTML contents as whole documents, and had to find out the hard way, how the library works under the hood.

In short:

- Some settings have to be tweaked
- Custom elements and attributes have to be added and configured

I've explained the approach for my use-case based on a shopware example in my blog: https://machinateur.dev/blog/how-to-sanitize-full-html-5-documents-with-htmlpurifier.